# Trigger next selected item automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select html that contains numbers (pages to select).  This select element calls another function when the selected option has been changed.  A function is being called the selected option has changed.

```
$("select#LogNavPage").change(function(){

    var pageNum = $("select#LogNavPage").val();

    $.ajax({        
        url: "serviceClient.aspx?Op=" + opCode,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: $.param({
            pageNum: pageNum, 
            categoryId: categoryId, 
            brandId: brandId, 
            seriesId: seriesId, 
            modelId: modelId, 
            productName: productName
        }),
        success: function(data){showEditProduct(data);}, 
        error: function(data){$("#ProdGenerator ul").append(data);}
    });
});
```

My objective is that, when I clicked on a button (**Previous** and **Next**), it will trigger also the select and also pick the next or the previous of the selected item.

The Next and Previous button is still empty.

```
$("#NextLog").click(function() {

    //trigger select change function here
});
```

Is it possible?  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't sounds too difficult, but it's unclear what you're asking without seeing more of your code.

Comment: The main question has been updated.  I don't know if I had specified what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KoalaBear/RAg8U/

```
$(document).on('change', '#LogNavPage', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});

$(document).on('click', '#Next', function() {
    $('#LogNavPage option:selected').prop('selected', false).next().prop('selected', true);
    $('#LogNavPage').trigger('change');
});

$(document).on('click', '#Previous', function() {
    $('#LogNavPage option:selected').prop('selected', false).next().prop('selected', true);
    $('#LogNavPage').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: The next() and prev() function worked for me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that you're asking for more than one thing, but here's a start:

```
$("#NextLog").click(function() {
    $('select#LogNavPage').trigger('change');
});
```